# Android Studio refused to show status bar nor Nav Bar

Tags: android-studio, web-design

I'm coding an app using Android Studio and the first thing I noticed is that it wouldn't display either status bar (the one with the hour and the battery) or the navigation bar (tha arrows and home button). I need them so my design is accurate-to-pixel when launching an emulator. I can't continue developing because the final product looks absolutely bad.
Help would be appreciated.

[this is the design view I follow along, with arrows pointing to the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oSxQW.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, don't mind, I found the answer in *another* answer, which said themselves found the answer by themselves, resulting in clicking the "**eye**" icon in Android Studio's viewport options bar.